# UI5 - OPA5 tests - simulate "right click" or "long press" or "context menu"

Tags: testing, sapui5, right-click, long-press

I am beginning with OPA5 tests in UI5 and I created a context menu that is shown when a button, label or an image is right-clicked or if user holds it on touch screen.

Now I need to write an OPA5 test for this. I can perform left-click using new sap.ui.test.actions.Press() but I am not able to do right-click or long-press.

https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.test.actions/overview

Can someone help, please?

I believe I would be able to write it in jQuery. And as UI5 is based on jQuery there should be a way but I do not know how to combine jQuery and UI5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Control has an event for RightClick, Hold etc. you should be able to call this Event in an Opa test somehow like:

```
                iRightClickMyControl: function () {
                    return this.waitFor({
                        id: "myControlId",
                        viewName: "myView",
                        actions: function (oControl) {
                            oControl.RightClick();
                        }
                        errorMessage: "myControl was not found."
                    });
                }
```

See "Writing Your Own Action" in
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/8615a0b9088645ae936dbb8bbce5d01d

Comment: Thanks for your idea. I ended up with this solution as well.